# Linux shell script to count occurance of char sequence in a text file?

Tags: linux, shell

I have a a large text file (over 70mb) and need to count the number of times a character sequence occurs in the file. I can find plenty of scripts to do this, but NONE OF THEM take in to account that a sequence can start and finish on different lines. For the sake of efficiency (I actually have way more than 1 file I am processing), I can not preprocess the files to remove newlines.

Example:
If I am searching for "thisIsTheSequence", the following file would have 3 matches:

```
asdasdthisIsTheSequence
asdasdasthisIsT
heSequenceasdasdthisIsTheSequ
encesadasdasda
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can preprocess the files, just do it in a pipeline before your counting script: `strip-newlines | count-matches`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just one awk script will do, since you will processing a huge file. Doing multiple pipes can slow down things.

```
#!/bin/bash
awk 'BEGIN{
 search="thisIsTheSequence"
 total=0
}
NR%10==0{
  c=gsub(search,"",s)
  total+=c  
}
NR{ s=s $0 }
END{ 
 c=gsub(search,"",s)
 print "total count: "total+c
}' file
```

output

```
$ more file
asdasdthisIsTheSequence
asdasdasthisIsT
heSequenceasdasdthisIsTheSequ
encesadasdasdaasdasdthisIsTheSequence
asdasdasthisIsT
heSequenceasdasdthisIsTheSequ
encesadasdasda
asdasdthisIsTheSequence
asdasdasthisIsT
heSequenceasdasdthisIsTheSequ
encesadasdasda

$ ./shell.sh
total count: 9
```

Answer (score 7):

One option:

```
echo $((`tr -d "\n" < file | sed 's/thisIsTheSequence/\n/g' | wc -l` - 1))
```

There are probably more efficient methods using utilities outside the core of shell - particularly if you can fit the file in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Is there ever going to be more than one newline in your sequence?

If not, one solution would be to split your sequence in half and search for the halves (e.g. search for "thisIsTh" and also for "eSequence"), then go back to the occurrences you find and take a "closer look", i.e. strip out the newlines in that area and check for a match.

Basically this is a kind of fast "filtering" of the data to find something interesting.

Comment: No, the sequence is 9 characters long. Lines with less than 9 characters are irrelevant to the search

Comment: In that case, you can search for the two halves of the sequence. If it's broken across two lines then you'll find at least ONE of the halves. This is basically a filtering technique that works well (fast) if the halves themselves are fairly rare. But it's a bit of effort to implement.

Answer (score -1):

use something like:

```
head -n LL filename | tail -n YY | grep text | wc -l
```

where LL is the last line of the sequence and YY is the number of lines in the sequence (i.e. LL -  first line)