# Linux Shell Script to extract data of email sent and mail back to admin

Tags: linux, shell

Here's the extract of the log file:

> Jan 18 02:30:11 qaapp2 sendmail[3126]: q0I7UBoS00312: to=, ctladdr= (10021/10000), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=120448, relay=buf-ex02.cymfony.com. [10.1.6.37], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent ( <201201180730.q0I7UBVW00312@qaapp2.cymfony.com> Queued mail for delivery)
>
> Jan 18 02:31:11 qaapp2 sendmail[3510]: q0I7VBOx00350: to=, ctladdr= (10021/10000), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=120453, relay=buf-ex02.cymfony.com. [10.1.6.37], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent ( <201201180731.q0I7VBei00350@qaapp2.cymfony.com> Queued mail for delivery)
>
> Jan 18 06:43:44 qaapp2 sendmail[442]: q0IBhisf00044: to=, ctladdr= (0/0), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=120450, relay=buf-ex02.cymfony.com. [10.1.6.37], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent ( <201201181143.q0IBhiSG00043@qaapp2.cymfony.com> Queued mail for delivery)

I want to know how many mails are sent to user `xyz@gmail.com` date wise from the log file located at the path `/var/log/maillog` file.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652548/linux-shell-script-to-count-occurance-of-char-sequence-in-a-text-file

Answer (score 2):

Whenever something needs counting, `wc` is your friend:

```
grep 'to=<xyz@gmail.com>' /var/log/maillog | wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check it via command mentioned below:

```
grep -i "to=<xyz@gmail.com" /var/log/maillog|wc -l; grep -i "to=<xyz@gmail.com" /var/log/maillog| awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$7,$13}'
```

In the above command, the first line will printed as number of mails that has been sent to the ID = xyz@gmail.com and beneath to it, you will have 'month', 'date', 'time', 'ID' followed by its 'status' of delivery.